# R: Running example of package function: strange behavior

Tags: r, package, argument-passing, function-call

I don't really understand why the behavior of `example` is different if I enter a string name manually from when I use the `ls` function. Consider the function below:

```
> ls("package:LIM")[1]
[1] "FILERigaAutumn"
```

If I run the example like that:

```
> example(ls("package:LIM")[1])
Warning message:
In example(ls("package:LIM")[1]) : no help found for ‘ls("package:LIM")[1]’
```

And it seems to not execute the example. 
But when I run it directly:

```
> example("FILERigaAutumn")
```

I get a lot of output and the example is executed.

The type of the argument passed seems to be the same:

```
> typeof("FILERigaAutumn")
[1] "character"
> typeof( ls("package:LIM")[1])
[1] "character"
```

Does anyone have an idea why?
I want to compute the running time of all the examples in one package:

```
for (func in ls("package:LIM")){system.time(example(func))}
```

Comment: Try `example(ls("package:LIM")[1], character.only=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`library`, `require`, `example` and maybe a few other functions could used with and without quotes:

```
example(runif)

example("runif")
```

To allow the unquoted version these functions convert the first argument into a character (without evaluating it) by calling:

```
deparse(subsitute(x))
```

resulting in:

```
deparse(substitute(ls("package:LIM")[1]))
# [1] "ls(\"package:LIM\")[1]"
```

To circumvent this (to evaluate the argument) you have to use the `character.only` argument.

```
example(ls("package:LIM")[1], character.only=TRUE)
```

IMHO this behaviour isn't very consistent (`character.only=TRUE` should be the default) and I can't see any advantages (ok, you can use tab-completion in the unquoted version).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification for the functions which can be run with and without quotes! I was always wondering why `library` and `require` can be used either way, but I never went to the bottom of it!